# PECL AMQP vs. php-amqp

Tags: php, amqp, pecl, php-amqp

I'm about to implement a system based on PHP that uses RabbitMQ. I can tell that there are 2 mature libraries out there: [PECL AMQP](http://php.net/manual/fa/book.amqp.php) and [php-amqp](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp).

I will be using PHP for both the client as well as the worker.

Does anybody have any practical experience with these 2 libraries? Is one better than the other for certain things? Are there any limitations when using any of these? Which one is more popular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Original answer (before question edit)**:

[PECL AMQP](http://php.net/manual/fa/book.amqp.php) is documentation (pretty outdated, btw) for [php-amqp](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp).

P.S.: there are amqp client library implementation in pure php - [php-amqplib](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib) which differs from PHP C extension [php-amqp](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp) in some parts, but which is best for you - is up to you and your needs.

Comment: That's good info, thanks. I have updated the question text to include this.

Comment: I have rolled back to the original question and accepted your answer. Will raise separate question for the libraries you mentioned. Sorry about the confusion - this was one of my first SO posts. Thanks again.